# Count from the selection to the last 3 quarters backawards

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have 2 tables in Oracle that I use in SSAS Tabular model :

MyFactTable
DimDate

The relationship beteween them is 1 to many
MyFactTable[FileExtractDate] to DimDate[Date]

A simple count of the RAF ID is
_count_Client_Distinct = COUNT(MyFactTable[Client ID])

now I want to calculate based on the selection the count of the RAF ID
and the last 3 quarters

For example:

if I select FileExtractDate= 12/10/2021
the visual of chart bars will give me the count of the Client ID of the Q4 since 12/10/2021 belongs to the 4th quarter
and displays the count of Client ID in the 3 other quarters (Q1, Q2, Q3)

if I select FileExtractDate= 09/02/2021
the visual of chart bars will give me the count of the Client ID of the Q1 since 09/10/2021 belongs to the 1st quarter
and displays the count of Client ID in the 3 other quarters (Q2, Q3, Q4) but for 2020

without any selection it will take the max date and show the count for the quarter of the max date and the last 3 quarters

I tried the following:

```
Prev 3 Qtrs = 
VAR _End = STARTOFQUARTER( 'Date'[Date] ) - 1
VAR _Start =
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( 'Date'[Date] ),
        DATEADD(
            DATEADD(
                'Date'[Date],
                -1,
                YEAR
            ),
            1,
            QUARTER
        )
    )
VAR _Result =
    CALCULATE(
        [Count],
        'Date'[Date] >= _Start
            && 'Date'[Date] <= _End
    )
RETURN
    _Result
```

But when I select a date it is showing only the result for the quarter to which that date belongs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a slicer or filter, it is not possible to display rows outside of the sliced/filtered range. What this means is you need a separate table for your visual (chart X-axis) and the one for the date slicer.

Here is my suggestion - create a duplicate Date table and maybe call it "Date Filter".

```
Date Filter = 'Date'
```

This new table does not need any relationships with any other table, so ensure none exist.

Then for your measure:

```
Prev 3 Qtr = 
  CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('MyFactTable'),
    KEEPFILTERS(
      DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date], ENDOFQUARTER('Date Filter'[Date]), -4, QUARTER)
    )
  )
```

[image]

To clarify:

- Slicer is from the `'Date Filter'` table
- Visual X-axis is from the `'Date'` table

Comment: I had to replace -3 to 0 to show data because I work on a part of it.
But when I select the date it is showing only the quarter to where the selection belongs

Comment: It will do that if you changed it to 0, which will give current quarter. Put it back to `-3` and make a selection, what happens?

Comment: no data is showing

Comment: Which table/column are you using for the slicer, and which table/column for the chart axis?

Comment: For the slicer I am using Date which has a 1 to Many relationship with the MyFactTable
in the chart I am supposed to use the measure and a column that I created in the Date table which is in this format "Q1 2023 Q2 2023..."

Comment: Here is a draft of my model https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NtDpMFRdNmtk6gcDwKCCXPnMepDz2T-E?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing the PBIX, makes it much easier to help. See updated fresh answer above.