# PowerBI Chart Year/Month Site by Side

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I am completely brand new to PowerBI and learning from YouTube. One thing I am stuck on his how to get a chart to have the previous year's month beside the current years month. This is what I currently have:

[PowerBI Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WemIr.png)
[Excel Chart - What I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYZfn.png)

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks,
Shea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a month column that just has the Month name like:

```
Month MMM = FORMAT([Date], "MMM")
```

Then use this as your X-Axis.

Looking at your screenshot - it seems you have a date table or two. These most likely have one already that you can use (so long as they have the correct realtionship in place).

For sorting this new Month column, you will need another Calculated Column. Try:

```
MonthFY_sort = 
  var mNum = MONTH([Date])
  return SWITCH( TRUE(),
    mNum > 9, mNum - 9,
    mNum + 3
  )
```

Then select the `Month MMM` column from previous, then in the ribbon, select `Sort by column` and select `MonthFY_sort` . That should take care of the sort order starting with Oct.

Comment: Thank you so much! Then is there a way of having the chart always run from October -> September as in financial year? Currently I can only get it running from Jan to Dec

Comment: See additional update to the answer above.

Comment: Thank you so much! Any chance you know how to do the 12 month rolling based on a month? I have been trying to get it to work, but it is not recognising the Amount for some reason

Comment: Best to post a new question on this with more details.

Comment: May be this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77786655/count-from-the-selection-to-the-last-3-quarters-backawards/77787091#77787091